# Webservers and POST requests

Tags: http, webserver

I am a beginner in handling web servers. I have a requirement where I would like to publish files into a particular location on a node as well as display the content on a web UI. Lets say these files are present on another node. How can i send these files from one node to another over HTTP? Do i need to have a web-server running on the destination node? And if that exists, can i send the files by using the `HTTP POST` option? Will the web server be capable of extracting the data from the request and writing it into the file system of the destination node. I just need an outline of how this works. What are the tools that are needed to set this up. I am not sure how to search for it in Google so having it as a question. There could be a million ways of doing this but my objective is to learn about the HTTP POST and GET methods mainly and whether this would be a solution to my requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by "node" ?

Comment: A Linux running machine - like a Raspberry Pi or a computer.